# How to read other language date with format and informat?

Tags: database, dataframe, sas, sas-macro, info

The saved dates in dataset are in German language:
12Mai2022
02Okt2020
06Dez2022

How convert/read such dates in sas with format and informat?

Comment: Are you asking how to attach a different format to date variables?  Use the FORMAT statement.

Answer (score 1):

Set your locale to `German_Germany` and use the `nldate.` informat.

```
options locale=German_Germany;

data want;
    date = input('12Mai2022', nldate.);

    format date date9.;
run;
```

Output:

```
date
12MAY2022
```